# close fancybox inside controller Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I have a form inside a fancybox.

The form is submitted with ajax.

Is it possible to close the fancybox from within the Rails controller?

And then redirect_to another webpage?

I am using Rails3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually for this kind of thing, in your AJAX callback if you get the response you're looking for, close the Fancybox with JS and redirect with JS. For example:

```
$.post('/some_route', { some: data }, function(res) {
  if(res.route) {
    $.fancybox.close();
    document.location = res.route;
  }
});
```